# libav - salvar captura de stream (segmentada) com timestamp no nome do arquivo

Tags: bash

Estava procurando na internet como fazer um DVR caseiro (usando uma máquina Linux) e o que eu encontrei foi esse comando avconv:

```
avconv -i rtsp://<user>:<password>@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/play1.sdp -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_format mp4 "capture-%03d.mp4"
```

Porém, como visto no comando, o padrão do nome do arquivo é sequencial (captura-001.mp4) e eu preciso do nome com a data e hora (captura-12-08-2017_15-54.mp4), e pesquisando a documentação do libav aparentemente só essa opção sequêncial é possível.

Gostaria de saber se é possível usando apenas o avconv e o bash (se sim como fazer), ou caso contrário de quais ferramentas preciso.

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme discussão [na versão em inglês dessa pergunta](https://superuser.com/questions/1240177/libav-output-segmented-stream-recording-with-the-current-timestamp), um usuário me recomendou mudar pro ffmpeg que já tem um atributo suportando timestamp, então eu consegui o que eu precisava com esse comando:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://<user>:<password>@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/play1.sdp -c copy -map 0 -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 1800 -segment_format mp4 out-%d_%m_%Y-%H_%M_%S.mp4`